# OutOfMemory exception when evaluating NumFound

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, solr.net

I have implemented Solr.net search in our project, and currently there are 660k docs in the index (size ~185 Mb).

Unfortunately, solr throws OutOfMemory exception every now and then:

> Error searching for contacts System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of
>   type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.  at
>   System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()  at
>   System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()  at
>   SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.ReadResponseToString(IHttpWebResponse
>   response) in c:\prg\SolrNet\SolrNet\Impl\SolrConnection.cs:line 213 
>   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request) in
>   c:\prg\SolrNet\SolrNet\Impl\SolrConnection.cs:line 199  at
>   SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable'1
>   parameters) in c:\prg\SolrNet\SolrNet\Impl\SolrConnection.cs:line 149 
>   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrQueryExecuter'1.Execute(ISolrQuery q, QueryOptions
>   options) in c:\prg\SolrNet\SolrNet\Impl\SolrQueryExecuter.cs:line 672 
>   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer'1.Query(ISolrQuery query, QueryOptions
>   options) in c:\prg\SolrNet\SolrNet\Impl\SolrBasicServer.cs:line 98  at
>   SolrNet.Impl.SolrServer'1.Query(ISolrQuery query, QueryOptions
>   options) in c:\prg\SolrNet\SolrNet\Impl\SolrServer.cs:line 49  at
>   SolrNet.Impl.SolrServer`1.Query(ISolrQuery q) in
>   c:\prg\SolrNet\SolrNet\Impl\SolrServer.cs:line 88  at
>   SearchService.Search.SolrSearch.SearchCount(String queryString,
>   Boolean exactSearch) in
>   c:\Projects\SearchService\Search\SolrSearch.cs:line 240

But the code is very simple:

```
public ISolrOperations<ContactForSearch> SolrInstance
{
    get
    {
        if (!_initialized)
        {
            Startup.Init<ContactForSearch>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SolrPath"));
            _initialized = true;
        }

        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<ContactForSearch>>();
    }
}

public virtual int SearchCount(string queryString, bool exactSearch)
{
    return SolrInstance.Query(GetGeneralSearchQuery(queryString, exactSearch)).NumFound;
}
```

It is possible that there are thousands of contacts to be returned with some queries, but I thought that `NumFound` should just get the count? So, how can I fix this problem? 
Thanks in advance for all advices!

Comment: Q: You're on a 64-bit OS (Windows Server?), Solr is running a 64-bit JVM, and you've targeted your Solr.Net app for a 64-bit CPU, correct?

Comment: I don't know how solr works, but you're not just getting a count, you're doing the full query and counting that.  You probably need to adjust the query to get the count directly.

Comment: @paulsm4, Yes I'm on Server 2012 R2 and target platform is Mixed
@JeffMercado, Not sure - there is no query like 'Count' or something that returns IEnumerable. The result of `Query` is SolrQueryResult<>

Comment: Again, be sure *everything* involved with your back-end Solr engine (OS, Java JVM, etc) is 64-bit, and has plenty of RAM. ADDITIONAL SUGGESTIONS: 1) Install [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and trace the offending "SearchCount" HTTP requests, 2) inspect the logs on your Solr server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the .NET client. In my experience, when you do a Solr query using the .NET client it will return the entire document from Solr not just the bit of the query you're interested in. You can try limiting your query to return 0 actual rows as this should still return the correct NumFound value.

Eg:

```
return SolrInstance.Query(query, new QueryOptions{ Rows = 0 }).NumFound;
```

Comment: @JleruOHeP yeah I couldn't remember the syntax off the top of my head. hope it fixed your problem